# How do you to convert a bson_t (older bson c type) to a bsoncxx::document?

Tags: c++, bson, mongo-cxx-driver

So far I've thought about using an iterator to manually fetch each field of the bson_t, something like this:

```
bsoncxx::builder::stream::document view_builder;
bson_iter_t iter;
bson_iter_init(&iter, &bson_t_doc);

while (bson_iter_next(&iter)) {
    const char* key = bson_iter_key(&iter);
    bson_type_t type = bson_iter_type(&iter);

    switch (type) {
        case BSON_TYPE_UTF8:
            view_builder << key << bsoncxx::types::b_utf8{bson_iter_utf8(&iter, nullptr)};
            break;
        case BSON_TYPE_INT32:
            view_builder << key << bsoncxx::types::b_int32{bson_iter_int32(&iter)};
            break;
        case BSON_TYPE_INT64:
            view_builder << key << bsoncxx::types::b_int64{bson_iter_int64(&iter)};
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

However this approach would need a pretty big and ugly switch with all supported types (granted for my use I could isolate only the ones used in the old bson_t documents...)

I have been trying to find an actual function for this but it seems that there isn't one. As a note, the bson_t type does not seem to expose the binary buffer at all so it seems I can't quickly access the binary data.

Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: Can you explain how you came into the posession of a `bson_t` without having access to the underlying binary buffer?

Comment: External library that uses bson_t in a structure that my application is consuming. I am however aiming to not have to include libbson at all in my code (instead using bsoncxx for everything). So far I've been successful with simple type conversions since the binary data has been accessible. If this is confusing, I apologize.



If I were to include libbson I could simply use `bson_get_data()` but I'd rather not. I'm also trying to find if there's any hacky way to do it but all I'm coming up with is using this function.

Comment: Well @LNorth it’s not a good idea because that approach is very inefficient. If you have the underlying binary data, you would be on the path to initializing a `bsoncxx::document::value` with that and manipulating thereafter will be a breeze. Re-consider your approach once more.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon what would be the better way? using both libbson and bsoncxx for this instance?

I do not have the underlying binary data outside of the bson_t pointer, that's the whole issue.

Answer (score 0):

"*If I were to include `libbson` I could simply use `bson_get_data()`*..."  why not do so?

> The `bson_get_data()` function shall return the **raw buffer of a bson** document. This can be used in conjunction with the `len` property of a `bson_t` if you want to copy the raw buffer around.
> [`bson_t::bson_get_data()`](https://mongoc.org/libbson/current/bson_get_data.html#description)

With the raw binary data and length, use these to instantiate a [`bsoncxx::document::view`.](https://mongocxx.org/api/current/classbsoncxx_1_1v__noabi_1_1document_1_1view.html#af1302e823c62c194fa4b1d9f30b43ef8)
This is more efficient than copying the binary data (could be 16mb in size) from the `bson_t` instance to a `bsoncxx::document::view` using `bsoncxx::builder::stream::document` like you did in your example.

Comment: I'd like to avoid it simply to avoid having to include libbson. Just a feeling of limiting my inclusions, but I've come to the realization that any other solution might be less efficient and unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: As a matter of fact; using any library that outputs bson_t will make libbson automatically available to your namespace because [the library already includes it and you are including the library.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive#Language_support)